# Conways Game Of Life Rendering

Tags: c#, conways-game-of-life

I've finished a game of life implementation but I'm running into a issue when rendering the grid after applying the game rules. I have a game loop that looks like this:

```
while (gameIsRunning)
{
    //Needed for accessing UIControls from the background
    //thread.

    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        //Process the array.
        MainBoard.Cells = engine.ApplyGameRules(MainBoard.Cells, MainBoard.Size.Height, MainBoard.Size.Width, BOARD_DIMENSIONS);
        //Check if there is a state such as
        //all states being dead, or all states being
        //alive.
        //Update the grid with the updated cells.
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                                     {
                                         timeCounter++;
                                         lblTimeState.Text = timeCounter.ToString();
                                         pictureBox1.Invalidate();
                                         pictureBox1.Update();
                                         Thread.Sleep(100);
                                     }));

        }
    }
```

and a draw function that looks like this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < MainBoard.Size.Height; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < MainBoard.Size.Width; y++)
    {
        Cell individualCell = MainBoard.Cells[y, x];
        if (individualCell.IsAlive() == false)
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, MainBoard.Cells[y, x].Bounds);
        }
        //White indicates that cells are alive
        else if (individualCell.IsAlive() == true)
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, MainBoard.Cells[y, x].Bounds);
        }
        else if (individualCell.IsInfected() == true)
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, MainBoard.Cells[y, x].Bounds);
        }
        //Draws the grid background itself.
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, MainBoard.Cells[y, x].Bounds);
    }
}
```

The problem that I'm running into is that I'm applying all of the game rules to every cell in the grid and then drawing that grid and then applying all the rules again so I never get the life form blobs that I should be seeing. Should the game rules be applied on a cell by cell basis so that its something along the lines of: Apply game rule to cell, draw grid, apply game rule to another cell, draw grid...?

Comment: As I understand it, you apply the rules to the entire grid and then redraw. So you need to take the state of the grid as it is and then update a *copy* based on the situation in the *original* grid.

Comment: Ok, I'll try something like that, I remember reading somewhere that a copy must be used when displaying the grid and I'm using the original to do both rule application and rendering.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the current intent of the program is correct.

What you should be doing is (pseudocode):

```
  Board oldBoard = new Board(start cell definitions);
  while(not finished) {
      Board newBoard = calculate(oldBoard);
      display(newBoard);
      oldBoard = newBoard();
  }
```

If you're not seeing the forms you expect, then either your display code is wrong, or your rule code is wrong.

In the pseudocode I'm throwing away the previous generation's board once it's no longer needed, and making a new board for each generation. `calculate()` contains a `new Board()` statement.

Of course if it's expensive to make a new board you could re-use one instead, and just flip back and forth between a "current" and "other" board. Just bear in mind that each time you write to a board, its new state must be 100% a function of the previous generation's state, and in no way affected by its own starting state. i.e. you must write to every cell.

An alternative method would be for each cell to hold two values. So instead of two boards with one value per cell, you have one board with each cell containing a "current" and "previous" value.

```
  Board board = new Board(initial state);
  while(not finished) {
      board.calculate(); // fills "current" cells based on "previous" cells.
      display(board);
      board.tick(); // "current" becomes "previous".
                    // "previous" becomes current, but is "dirty" until calculated.
  }
```

There are lots of ways you could do it. One way is:

```
  public class Cell {
      private boolean[] state = new boolean[2];
      private int generation = 0;

      public void setCurrentState(boolean state) {
          state[generation] = state;
      }

      public void getCurrentState() {
          return state[generation];
      }

      public void getLastState() {
          return state[ (generation + 1) % 2 ];
      }

      public void tick() {
          generation = (generation + 1) % 2;
      }

  }
```

Comment: On that last line in the pseudo, are all the old cells being re-initialized?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I'm still not sure I understand directly. For example, in my code my MainBoard.Cells is the 2 dimensional array or the table. I apply the rules to this table, and then redraw that table in one generation. My initial state is all cells are alive. Generation 2 I use that same MainBoard.Cells which now has the updated state for each cell. I apply the rules again and redraw. Also every cell in my table has an isAlive property to determine if dead or alive.

Comment: The problem with doing that is that when you calculate cell(n), it needs to know the state of cell(n-1) in the previous generation. You may just have changed the value of cell(n-1).

Comment: So for example with a 4x4 grid where all cells start alive as the starting state. If I calculate a new board based on the starting board only, then every cell would be dead? Because In using the original board cell by cell, every cell in the new board would be dead from overcrowding. Then this new board becomes a previous board and another new board needs to be generated for generation three correct?

Comment: Correct. To get interesting results you have to initialise your first grid with a pattern that will live.